# Unable to install user-wide terminal integration with vcpkg on macOS

Tags: bash, macos, vcpkg

I'm trying to get Vcpkg user-wide bash integration following the [official instructions](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg). here are the steps I took:

1. `git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git`
2. `cd vcpkg`
3. `./bootstrap-vcpkg.sh`
4. `./vcpkg integrate install`

> Applied user-wide integration for this vcpkg root.
>
> CMake projects should use: "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/path/to/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"

5. `./vcpkg integrate bash`

> Unable to read /Users/<user>/.bashrc

6. `touch /Users/<user>/.bashrc` and repeat step 5

> Adding vcpkg completion entry to /Users/<user>/.bashrc

7. `mv /Users/<user>/.bashrc /Users/<user>/.bash_profile`

However, now when I run `vcpkg` or `./vcpkg` in new terminals I get:

> -bash: vcpkg: command not found

I would appreciate it if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can resolve it.

My environment is:

- macOS Catalina version 10.15.4
- GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19)

**P.S.** I was asked [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/bash/comments/fvb45a/unable_to_install_userwide_terminal_integration/fmhps9s?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) to show the content of the `.bash_profile` is:

```
source /path/to/vcpkg/scripts/vcpkg_completion.bash
```

Answer (score 7):

A temporary solution was to add the line:

```
export PATH=/path/to/vcpkg:$PATH
```

to the `.bash_profile`. Wonder why the above installation/integration scripts don't do this automatically!

Answer (score -1):

the vcpkg integrate command didn't do a thing for me.

I added a path for vcpkg and cmake which is buried deep in the vcpkg structure and then I used the --toolchain option for cmake as suggested in point 4 of the original post. CMake projects should use: MAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/path/to/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"

Comment: this doesn't seem like an answer to me. chances are that you will be downvoted and your post will be deleted by the moderators.